# React setState for multi level state object

Tags: reactjs, setstate, react-component, react-state, react-state-management

I'm trying to update my state object which contains multiple levels. See this example https://codesandbox.io/s/oq9kp9vy5y.

The problem is, that the values in the render method, does not update ... only the first one. Can I force an update or is there a better way?

Thanks
Kasper

Comment: You should include relevant code snippets as opposed to just a link, as the link could break.

Comment: Why are you setting state in `componentDidMount()`? Why not just have it be your initial state?

Comment: You are updating one value (state.kitchen) and rendering another (state.calcuatedUsage.kitchen).

Comment: I actually find the codesandbox link very helpful. It made it much easier for me to help debug.

Comment: @ShaneCavaliere "If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - but also include the code in your question itself. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time." - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Fair enough, good point :)

Comment: @Galupuf, next time I'll include relevant code, thanks for the guidelines. The reason why I'm updating my state object in componentDidMount() is only to give a simple example.

Comment: @ShaneCavaliere, thanks I agree with you:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your initial state, you have the `kitchen` object **inside** the `calculatedUsage` object. But in your `setState` call, you have the `kitchen` object **outside** of `calculatedUsage`.

Also, when you are accessing the previous state within `setState`, it's best to use the functional version of `setState`, e.g.:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.setState(
    prevState => ({
      caclulatedUsage: {
        ...prevState.caclulatedUsage,
        bath: 12,
        kitchen: {
          ...prevState.caclulatedUsage.kitchen,
          stove: 14,
          fridge: 23,
          dishwasher: 34
        }
      }
    }),
    () => {
      console.log(this.state);
    }
  );
}
```

The reason for this is that `setState` can be asynchronous, which means that accessing `this.state` within it may not give you the value you expect. Using the functional version for transactional state changes guarantees consistent results.

You may also want to take a look at the [immer](https://github.com/mweststrate/immer) library. It makes updating deeply nested state much easier, by allowing you to do immutable updates with a mutable API. Here's a fork of your codesandbox example that uses immer: https://codesandbox.io/s/180p7p0o84

Comment: ...and Immer looks great, I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      caclulatedUsage: {
        bath: 0,
        kitchen: {
          stove: 0,
          fridge: 0,
          dishwasher: 0
        },
        livingroom: {
          tv: 0,
          tvBox: 0
        }
      }
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState(
      {
        caclulatedUsage: Object.assign({}, this.state.access, {
          caclulatedUsage: {
            ...this.state.caclulatedUsage,
            bath: 12
          },
          kitchen: {
            ...this.state.caclulatedUsage.kitchen,
            stove: 14,
            fridge: 23,
            dishwasher: 34
          }
        })
      },
      () => {
        console.log(this.state);
      }
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        {this.state.caclulatedUsage.bath}
        <br />
        {this.state.caclulatedUsage.kitchen.stove}
        <br />
        {this.state.caclulatedUsage.kitchen.fridge}
        <br />
        {this.state.caclulatedUsage.kitchen.dishwasher}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: This should be the correct Never mutate this.state . Treat this.state as if it were immutable. But whats the point of setting state in componentDidMount() ?

Comment: This example accesses `this.state` inside of the `this.setState` call, which is not a good idea. If you need to access the previous state while updating, you should use the functional version of `this.setState`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState(
      {
        caclulatedUsage: {
          ...this.state.caclulatedUsage,
          bath: 12,
           kitchen: {
               ...this.state.caclulatedUsage.kitchen,
               stove: 14,
               fridge: 23,
               dishwasher: 34
           }
        }

      }
      () => {
        console.log(this.state);
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: This example accesses `this.state` inside of the `this.setState` call, which is not a good idea. If you need to access the previous state while updating, you should use the functional version of `this.setState`.